# Change format for Duration field in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using `django` `DurationField` in a model to calculate the time difference between two `DateTimeField`.

On the admin site for that model, the field shows up like this:

```
# short duration
Cumulative Total time:   0:51:33
# longer duration
Cumulative Total time:   2 days, 3:10:21
```

Is it possible to change the format for this field to the below given format?

```
Cumulative Total time:   2 days, 3 hours, 10 minutes, 21 seconds
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) has the following code that relates to formatting:

```
...
from django.utils.duration import duration_string
...

class DurationField(Field):
    ...
    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        val = self.value_from_object(obj)
        return '' if val is None else duration_string(val)
```

and the function `duration_string` looks like this:

```
def duration_string(duration):
    """Version of str(timedelta) which is not English specific."""
    days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds = _get_duration_components(duration)

    string = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    if days:
        string = '{} '.format(days) + string
    if microseconds:
        string += '.{:06d}'.format(microseconds)

    return string
```

---

One solution is to create your custom field that overrides the one method listed above:

```
from django.utils.duration import _get_duration_components

class CustomDurationField(DurationField):
    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        val = self.value_from_object(obj)
        if val is None:
            return ''

        days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds = _get_duration_components(val)
        return '{} days, {:02d} hours, {:02d} minutes, {:02d}.{:06d} seconds'.format(
            days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds)
```

You would need to tweak the exact output to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Serializer` and `DurationField` you have to change `value_to_string()` to `to_representation()`

```
class DurationField(Field):
    ...
    def to_representation(self, value):
       return duration_string(value)
```

where `duration_string()` has the same implementation as above